# Websocket Single Reader Sample Error in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jvm

In my JMX file, I am using WebSocket single reader sampler and running the no of users as 2450 with ramp-up time is 150 sec. But after a few minutes, I am getting the below error.

> WebSocket Single Read Sampler, Sampler error, "Sampler configured for using the existing connection, but there is no connection", Thread Group 1-18

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case your application gets overloaded and cannot setup the connection within the bounds of 20 seconds default timeout therefore `WebSocket Open Connection` fails and hence when `WebSocket Single Read Sampler` is being executed there is no connection to "read" from and it fails as well.

If you want to avoid this type of errors the options are in:

1. Choose different behaviour on Sampler error under [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   [image]
2. Put your `WebSocket Single Read Sampler` under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and click "Use status of last sample" button, this way all the If Controller's children will be executed only if open connection sampler will be successful:

   [image]